# Implement IF & MIN logic in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table in ACCESS. I need to implement a SQL query/macro to add another field to it.

```
ID F1 F2 F3
1   1  2  3
2   5  6  9
3   4  2  3
```

I need to add a field F4 which has the following formula :-

```
F4 = IF(MIN(F1,F2-F3)>0,MIN(F1,F2-F3),0)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried googling for "ms access sql min" and "ms access sql if"? If yes, what have you tried then and what was the problem?

Comment: Well I am pretty new to SQL. But from what I googled & read MIN can be implemented on the entire column at one time.

Comment: Can you implement `MIN` using `IF`? Can you use the observation that `MIN(F1,F2-F3)>0` is the same as `(F1 > 0) And (F2-F3 > 0)`?

Comment: Yeah so I got the if-condition part, but if its true, i need the MIN(F1,F2-F3) part. And that is giving an error of wrong number of arguments; which it should as MIN is supposed to take only one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement a minimum function you can follow this Knowlegde Base article: [ACC2000: How to Find Minimum or Maximum Value Across Fields of Record](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209857/en-us).

Then, your query in Access should be something like:

```
SELECT f1, f2, f3, IIF(Minimum(f1, f2-f3)>0,Minimum(f1, f2-f3),0)  AS f4
FROM tempDb
```

Comment: Min(F1,F2-F3) gives an error of wrong number of arguments.

Comment: @ArkaSarkar Don't change the name suggested by the Knowledge Article for the function, expecially if you are a newbie.

Comment: Minimum() function gives me an undefined function in expression error.

Comment: @ArkaSarkar Have you followed the instructions of the Knowledge Base article at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209857/en-us? Have you created a new module with the Minimum function?

Comment: Done & Done! Thanks a ton! Did not compile before. Thanks a ton GmG. :-)